# Stored procedure error in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to run this query, where can be the error, because it's ok., thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
   @PageSize int,
   @PageNumber int 
AS
   SELECT 
       PK_ID, Test, Descripcion 
   FROM 
      (SELECT
           PK_ID, Test, Descripcion, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Test, PK_ID) AS RowNumber 
      FROM 
        Mydatabase
     ) AS Test
WHERE 
    RowNumber BETWEEN @PageSize * @PageNumber AND @PageSize * (@PageNumber)
```

Comment: If it is ok, why is there an error?

Comment: And what is the error you receive?

Comment: I don't think your where clause is correct. Both ends are the same, so this query can only return 0 or 1 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your pages are numbered (starting from 0 or from 1), you should probably change your `WHERE` clause to one of these:

1. If the page numbers start from 0:

   ```
   WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @PageSize * @PageNumber + 1
                       AND @PageSize * (@PageNumber + 1)
   ```
2. If the page numbers start from 1:

   ```
   WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) + 1
                       AND @PageSize * @PageNumber
   ```

Comment: all the issue was `+1` .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a page to the upper limit of your page range:

```
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @PageSize * @PageNumber 
AND @PageSize * (@PageNumber + 1) -- added 1 here
```